# is it possible/correct for a class (not an instance) to act as a delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols, static-methods

I'm building the iOS app that is to act as a client for a REST server. So far I've been handling my all my requests in a very simple manner. Whenever I needed to make a call, I'd do something like:

```
[ApiRequestManager sendApiCall:@"dogs/getSomeDog"
                    withParams:@{ @"dog_name": @"freddo" }
                      callback:^(NSDictionary *result) {
                          // do something with the response data already unserialized
                          // (comes as JSON) by the ApiRequestManager static method.
                      }];
```

As the app grows in complexity I realize it would be much cleaner (and less of an effort to test) if I actually subclassed `NSMutableURLRequest` and made my own protocol for responses, like this:

```
@protocol ApiRequestDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)apiRequest:(ApiRequest *)request didSucceedWithResult:(NSDictionary *)result;

@optional
- (void)apiRequest:(ApiRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

This allows me to separate the code for building requests and handling their responses, among other things. It was all fine and dandy when I started to replace my old calls using the delegation pattern, but! I then realized that here and there, I was doing things like these:

```
// in class Dog
+ (void)putLeashOnDogs:(NSArray *)dogs {
    NSString *ids = // collect IDs from dogs

    [ApiRequestManager sendApiCall:@"dogs/putLeash"
                        withParams:@{ @"dog_ids": ids }
                          callback:^(NSDictionary *result) {
                              // something
                          }];
}
```

My question is, can I somehow say "this class is to have a static version of the X protocol methods" and then, in the static method in which I create the delegating object (that would be the ApiRequest instance) just say `myRequest.delegate = self` ?
If I can't or there's a better/cleaner/more correct way to solve this, what options do I have?

Comment: What you have with a callback is MUCH, MUCH cleaner than spaghetti code with delegates.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but it sounds like the problem you're having is analogous to the problem of doing multiple simultaneous downloads with NSURLConnection - namely, that for every such NSURLConnection we need a separate delegate to receive the results. If so, I think the simple solution is not to unify at the class level but just the opposite, to embody everything that needs to separate as a separate object.

I have a class MyDownloader that has a `connection` property along with all the delegate methods. To use it, we instantiate it, initialize the `connection` property, and tell it to start. Each MyDownload is responsible for its own NSURLConnection, and is the delegate for that connection. We have now effectively pushed the problem up a level: instead of herding the cats of the multiple NSURLConnections, we are now herding the cats of the multiple MyDownloader instances, each of which must be retained at least until its download has finished. But that is an easy problem; a minimalist solution is to store them in an NSMutableSet, for instance.

Okay, was that *any* help or did I just spend two paragraphs talking about something utterly irrelevant to your question?

Comment: I think you are correct if that matters.... I would add that the op looks to be using kind of a factory pattern (maybe has java experience? dunno) and it it totally valid in that context to initialize a delegate in the factory... if you can figure out a clean way to hand off ownership of it...

Comment: @GradyPlayer I'm sure there's a Design Pattern for that!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original language question: A class object could implement delegate methods as class methods, but there's no way to declare that the class object itself conforms to the delegate protocol's instance methods. It's possible to pacify the compiler with type casts, but any delegate APIs that check the delegate object's protocols at runtime won't work properly.